# Am I maximising my A0 readout rate with this peak-detection code?

Tags: code-review, code-optimization

I have a pulse going into A0 on a Nano, and want to detect the peak voltage.  With low-pass filtering to slow down the input pulse I'm still reading marginally too slow.

The code overall inhibits a laser except for 50ms after a button is pressed.  During that 50ms I read A0 to look for the peak voltage/laser pulse energy.  The pulse is negative, several volts, and is AC-coupled into A0, pulled up to a 5V baseline.

The monitoring loop is simple:

```cpp
while (millis() < (PulseStart + LaserPulseWidth)) { // monitor ADC (PbSe amplified photodiode with negative output, AC coupled and pulled up
  if (V_in <= V_old) {
    V_old = V_in;
  } // this will report the minimum voltage seen on the monitor pin.  Should be near enough proportional to the pulse energy.
  V_in = analogRead(MonitorPin);
}
```

Outside the monitoring loop, but in the main loop, I toggle various status LEDs etc.  The resulting laser pulse energy is sent using `softwareSerial` to (a Raspberry Pi in) the box with the trigger button, about 12m away. `softwareSerial` requires interrupts, but anyway so does `millis()`

[image: Oscilloscope image of input pulse]

Channel 1 (yellow) is measured at A0.  Channel 2 is the unfiltered output from the PbSe amplified IR photodiode, and is used to trigger the scope.  Note the timebase is 100us, close to the nominal readout time of A0; I thought this would effectively average over approximately 1 division, which might be OK, but taking some rough calibration data suggests otherwise.

Here's my circuit:
[image: partial circuit/block diagram]

A simplified version of the whole code follows. I've removed some status outputs (LEDs, beeps, USB serial transmssion) from the main loop and the code to set them up; the ADC read-in loop is unmodified from my running code.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
  
int MonitorPin = A0;
int FireButton;
int stopbutton;
int lastFireButton = LOW;
int V_in;
int V_old;
char message[8];
int V_base;
int LaserPulseWidth = 50; //in ms.  50 ms should be right for 20 Hz laser
    
SoftwareSerial mySerial = SoftwareSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX
    
void setup() {
  pinMode(pin7, INPUT_PULLUP);  // fire laser
  pinMode(pin8, INPUT_PULLUP);  // disable
  stopbutton = digitalRead(8);
  FireButton = digitalRead(7);  
  pinMode(LaserPin, OUTPUT); // Laser trigger pin
  Serial.begin(9600); // for comms to a host PC (includes debug info)
  mySerial.begin(9600); // for comms to RPi
  mySerial.println("Second serial port");
  interrupts();
}
    
void loop() {
  stopbutton = digitalRead(8);
  FireButton = digitalRead(7);
  while (stopbutton == HIGH) { // not actually used, but implemented in case we want to suppress firing (pin internally pulled up so just ground to suppress)
    lastFireButton = FireButton;
    stopbutton = digitalRead(8);
    FireButton = digitalRead(7);
    V_old = 1024; // initialise to max so anything we read is less
    
    if (FireButton != lastFireButton && FireButton == LOW) { // detect negative edge
      digitalWrite(13, true); // flash the onboard status LED on
      V_old = 1024;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        V_in += analogRead(MonitorPin); // read ADC before firing to provide a baseline
      }
      V_base = V_in / 10;
      digitalWrite(LaserPin, true); // laser trigger on
      PulseStart = millis();
      while (millis() < (PulseStart + LaserPulseWidth)) { //monitor ADC (PbSe amplified photodiode with negative output, AC coupled and pulled up
        if (V_in <= V_old) {
          V_old = V_in;
        } // this will report the minimum voltage seen on the monitor pin.  Should be near enough proportional to the pulse energy.
        V_in = analogRead(MonitorPin);
      }
      digitalWrite(LaserPin, false); // laser trigger on
          
      int V_peak = V_base - V_old;
      sprintf(message, "ADC=%d", V_peak);
      mySerial.println(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote; to handle millis rollover, use `while ( (millis()-PulseStart) < LaserPulseWidth) ` instead.

Comment: Do you have a schematic, and an oscilloscope picture of the pulse as it is, and as it arrives at the Arduino pin? Just to get some idea of what "a little too fast" is. `analogRead()` is quite slow by default, but can be sped up.

Comment: You could you do like, say, 20 measurements, and store those in an array. Then afterward see which value was the peak value. That way your code doesn't have to do a `millis` call, and two comparisons, making it run a bit faster. If that's not enough, you'd have to change the prescaler of the ADC, to get a faster Analog to Digital conversion.

Comment: @Gerben the pulse can occur anywhere within a window of 50ms (the laser has a 20Hz rep rate; I allow emission for 1/20 s to get one pulse).  I don't think I've got enough storage to read flat out for 50ms then post-process.

Comment: @ocrdu I'll get a scope trace with the latest circuit.  I've been building a low-pass filter this morning, since posting.  My schematic needs updating.  It was a simple block diagram before I started AC-coupling and low-pass filtering

Comment: Actually (@Gerben) I'm right on the edge of having enough storage.  The compiler says I've got 1103B free for local variables, which is enough for 550 ints or 55ms if I read every 100us.  I'm not sure if all that is actually free, but I could free up some more.

Comment: @ocrdu I've added the circuit; it's more of an electronic lab-book sketch but hopefully clear enough

Comment: `"On ATmega based boards (UNO, Nano, Mini, Mega), it takes about 100 microseconds (0.0001 s) to read an analog input"`. Your pulse only takes 50µs. So you need to increase the ADC speed, by changing the prescaler.

Comment: What is it you are trying to measure? The peak-voltage, or the time till the peak occurs?

Comment: @Gerben I've been looking into that and will almost certainly do so.  What's not clear to me is how much is settling time (effectively averaging? or so I hoped) and how much is dead time.  Also my scope's  negative peak width measurement is unhelpful.  This trace has a "?" after it, not all do, but the number is always >~100us.  I'm after peak V; I'll add that to the Q.... I think it was clearer before one of my edits

Comment: The ADC averaging time is not specified, but probably tiny compared to the conversion time. Have you considered using a diode-based peak detector?

Comment: @EdgarBonet previous tests had showed this to be a rather slow (several hundred us) photodiode so I had expected not to need a significant sampling circuit.  Partly it's because I'm designing/building my electronics at home and testing/using them in work (the laser takes up most of a room, but we're supposed to work from home where possible).  The former slowness may be a thermal effect as the photodiode is sensitive out to 4.8um.  The laser pulses are a few picoseconds BTW.  The photodiode amplifier is internal. Changing the clock prescale is looking helpful so far.

Comment: I could also use an MCP3002 over SPI; that's faster and I've got some on rather large boards I'm not using

Comment: There's also a way to put the ADC into free-running mode, and it will sample into an array at the maximum possible speed all on its own. There's an adafruit tutorial on it, but I've never done this myself. I *believe* this part does not require external hardware: https://learn.adafruit.com/wave-shield-voice-changer/principles-of-operation